# Multiple steps getting activated while adding custom step at checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.1

I have added a custom step in checkout due to which next step is also getting activated along with the custom step. Since my quote is virtual, shipping step is hidden and only custom step and payment step are getting displayed together.

Following is the code i have tried.

ST/Employees/view/frontend/web/js/view/login.js

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
    * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
    *
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'ST_Employees/login'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'login',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Collection Point',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                * sort order value
                * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                0
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
        * for switching to your custom step
        */
        navigate: function () {
            self.visible(false);
        },

        /**
        * @returns void
        */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If your new step is the first step, you have to create mixins for the payment and shipping steps. Otherwise two steps will be activated on loading of the checkout. check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: Still not working